# File writer not typing in file (Java)

Tags: java

I made a program to produce a file with numbers in it
But the program is not typing any thing in the file it created!

This is the code:

```
     private void OpenMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    ModFile=new File(NameText.getText() + ".mod");
    FileWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(ModFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   if(!ModFile.exists()){
   try {
   ModFile.createNewFile();
   System.out.println("Mod file has been created to the current directory");
   writer.write(CodesBox.getText());
   } catch (IOException ex) {
   Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
     }     
   }
```

When i create a random file, i don't see any thing when i open it!
Please help
Thanks Amir for helping but i noticed i should use FileOutputStream and DataOutputStream...
So, i need help again cause the same problem appeared :(

```
 File ModFile =new File(NameText.getText() + ".mod");
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ModFile);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
    int i = Integer.parseInt(CodesBox.getText());
    dos.writeInt(i);
        // and other processing 
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ModMakerGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}finally{
    try{
         dos.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

NetBeans said they cannot find the symbol dos at (dos.close();)

Please help me here again

Comment: add `writer.close();`, this will also flush everything not written yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have to check that file name is present in `NameText.getText()`.
- You dont need to create file, if file dont exist FileWriter will create it self.
- You should Close file after processing

  private  void OpenMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

  ```
      //check before file name is nt null
      File ModFile =new File("somefile" + ".mod");
      FileWriter writer = null;

      try {
          writer = new FileWriter(ModFile);
          writer.write("test..................");
              // and other processing 
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }finally{
          try {
              writer.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

  }
  ```

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
to use `FileOutputStream` and write byte array follow the following code

```
private static void OpenMenuActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {  

//check before file name is nt null
    File ModFile =new File("somefile" + ".mod");
    FileOutputStream writer = null;

    String toProcess = "00D0C0DE00D0C0DE F000000000000000";

    try {
        writer = new FileOutputStream(ModFile);
        writer.write(toProcess.getBytes(),0,toProcess.getBytes().length);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }finally{
        try {
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You should add null-check in finally block.

Comment: this is just hint.... a working hint ... programmer must impose all kind of validations by it self.

Comment: I'm having another problem :( I changed to FileOutputStream cause i wanted it to write in hex and not strings. Please help

Comment: I did little modification to demonstrate how bytes can be write with  `FileOutputStream`

Comment: take a look this link as well http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/214796/writing-a-string-of-hex-files-to-a-file

Comment: I am not able to save the file after trying to use them.

Comment: what code u are following , i tried the above code it was working, what exception you are getting

Comment: did u test this code ` FileOutputStream writer = new FileOutputStream(ModFile);writer.write(toProcess.getBytes(),0,toProcess.getBytes().length);` That i had change and it is working

Comment: I just noticed that i changed the wrong code... Sorry about that but i wanted the numbers to be in hex, when i open the file it is still written as a string

Comment: my above code in writing hex information in (.mod) file.Go through the link i put in reference as well